# How do you set an MP3 added with python-pptx to play in click sequence?

Tags: python-pptx

I am trying to get an MP3 file I added to play in the click sequence. When I add it this way, not only does it not have "play in click sequence" selected (as it would be if I added it manually), it doesn't have any triggers at all.

[image: screenshot of PowerPoint showing there's no indication of when the MP3 file should start]

I've tried Googling it, and I've compared the code for "play in click sequence" vs not, and searched the documentation, and I haven't found anything for it.

Code snippet (it inserts the MP3 but does not let it play in click sequence):

```
    music = slide.shapes.add_movie(
        music_path,
        left=Inches(4.17),
        top=Inches(6.74),
        width=Inches(1.67),
        height=Inches(0.76),
        poster_frame_image=None,
        mime_type='audio/mp3')
```

Is there something I need to add to set it to Start "In Click Sequence"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, based on this 2 issues on Github:

- https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/400
- https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/502

It seems like currently there's still no Animation support on `python-pptx` yet. If you try to use Powerpoint manually, you will notice that adding a play in click sequence will automatically add a Animation event (that triggers during `On click` / `With previous`)

Comment: Darn. Well, I figured out a workaround to make it play when you get to the slide and another one to hide the media during the show. If I figure this one out I'll try to remember to come back here and explain.

Comment: This is probably yet another case of "let's look at the XML and figure out how to confect it". Unfortunately in my python-pptx based queue of things to do this can't rank highly. (I don't use video in my work presentations so won't add this to md2pptx any time soon.)